# Android emulator Mac OSX location

Tags: android, macos, osx-snow-leopard, android-virtual-device

Where does Android emulator keep all its data and itself?

Inside the SDK folder or somewhere else?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the AVD that you are creating for your simulator. By default, the AVD Manager creates the AVD directory inside ~/.android/avd/

You can check this link to get more info

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#DefaultLocation

Answer (score 9):

- Open the AVD manager
- Right-click one of the devices
- Select "Show on Disk"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the files stored on the emulator, you can use the [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) that comes with the Android Studio.

Your app should be in `/data/data/<you-app-id>`